# API access still disabled after successful audit

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My YouTube API access was disabled and I was asked to submit the YouTube audit form.
I've gone through the YouTube audit process successfully but when using the API I still get the following error:

```
    `{

      "error": {

      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
        "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project xxxxxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
        "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxxx"
       }
      ],
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project xxxxxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
    }

}`
```

When going to the link mentioned above it shows that the YouTube API is enabled.

[image: YouTube API status]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to enable it.

Comment: I only have the option to disable it on the console so it must be enabled.